# Failed to accept a connection.: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, spring, ejb

I am getting below error in JBoss ide and server JBoss 7.1

```
14:42:35,330 WARN  [org.hornetq.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl] (hornetq-failure-check-thread) Java heap space: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

14:42:35,375 WARNING [org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioServerSocketPipelineSink] (Old I/O server boss ([id: 0x0095146e, localhost/127.0.0.1:6455])) Failed to accept a connection.: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

14:42:43,397 ERROR [org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory] (Thread-0 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=6ba001c9-31f8-11ea-a949-4437e6a1cfcc-9252887)) Caught unexpected Throwable: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

14:42:43,397 WARNING [org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioServerSocketPipelineSink] (Old I/O server boss ([id: 0x012e6421, localhost/127.0.0.1:6445])) Failed to accept a connection.: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

14:42:47,337 ERROR [org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory] (Thread-24 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=6ba001c9-31f8-11ea-a949-4437e6a1cfcc-9252887)) Caught unexpected Throwable: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Comment: there is a memory leak in your application @mowgli, i suggest you to take an heap dump of the jvm and then analyse the dump with some heap dump analyser like mat

Answer (score 1):

You can analyze from heap dump of your code, you can use jvisualvm or any other tool.
You can also use java inbuilt command for that which captures heap dump on `outOfMemoryError`

Command-line option that generates a heap dump when a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is thrown:

```
java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

By default, it stores the dump in a java_pid.hprof file in the directory where we're running the application. If we want to specify another file or directory we can set it in the HeapDumpPath option:

```
java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=<file-or-dir-path>
```